# Problem in cross compiling linux kernel 4.4.2 for ARM in ubuntu

Tags: gcc

I followed the below  procedure in compiling the linux 4.4.2 kernel and gcc

```
verion is gcc version 4.7.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-12ubuntu1) 
ravi@ravi-Inspiron-3537:~/linux$ make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPLILE=arm-linux-gnueabi- vexpress_defconfig
#
# configuration written to .config
#
ravi@ravi-Inspiron-3537:~/linux$ make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPLILE=arm-linux-gnueabi- 
scripts/kconfig/conf  --silentoldconfig Kconfig
  CHK     include/config/kernel.release
  CHK     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
make[1]: `include/generated/mach-types.h' is up to date.
  CC      kernel/bounds.s
gcc: error: unrecognized argument in option ‘-mabi=aapcs-linux’
gcc: note: valid arguments to ‘-mabi=’ are: ms sysv
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mlittle-endian’
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mno-thumb-interwork’
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mfpu=vfp’
make[1]: *** [kernel/bounds.s] Error 1
make: *** [prepare0] Error 2
```

How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: You need to be using the ARM version of GCC, not the Ubuntu version with some switches.  The whole ARM toolchain needs to be set up, usually through defined variables like CC=${myarmtools}/gcc   etc.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the topic?

Answer (score 0):

You can install the arm toolchain in your own directory.  Then set up a set of definitions like:

```
    MY_ARM_BASE=${HOME}/dev/toolchain/arm-2008q3
    C_INCLUDE_PATH=${MY_ARM_BASE}/lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.3.2/include:${MY_ARM_BASE}/lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.3.2/include-fixed
    LIBRARY_PATH=${MY_ARM_BASE}/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/lib:${MY_ARM_BASE}/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/lib
    CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=${MY_ARM_BASE}/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.3.2
    #OBJC_INCLUDE_PATH
    COMPILER_PATH=${MY_ARM_BASE}/bin
    #LD_RUN_PATH
    #GPROF_PATH
    #######
    CC=${COMPILER_PATH}/gccMY_ARM_BASE=${HOME}/dev/toolchain/arm-2008q3 C_INCLUDE_PATH=${MY_ARM_BASE}/lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.3.2/include:${MY_ARM_BASE}/lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.3.2/include-fixed LIBRARY_PATH=${MY_ARM_BASE}/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/lib:${MY_ARM_BASE}/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/lib CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=${MY_ARM_BASE}/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.3.2
#OBJC_INCLUDE_PATH COMPILER_PATH=${MY_ARM_BASE}/bin
#LD_RUN_PATH
#GPROF_PATH
#######MY_ARM_BASE=${HOME}/dev/toolchain/arm-2008q3 C_INCLUDE_PATH=${MY_ARM_BASE}/lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.3.2/include:${MY_ARM_BASE}/lib/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.3.2/include-fixed LIBRARY_PATH=${MY_ARM_BASE}/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/lib:${MY_ARM_BASE}/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/libc/usr/lib CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=${MY_ARM_BASE}/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.3.2
#OBJC_INCLUDE_PATH COMPILER_PATH=${MY_ARM_BASE}/bin
#LD_RUN_PATH
#GPROF_PATH
####### CC=${COMPILER_PATH}/gcc CXX=${COMPILER_PATH}/g++ RANLIB=${COMPILER_PATH}/ranlib STRIP=${COMPILER_PATH}/strip export C_INCLUDE_PATH LIBRARY_PATH CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH COMPILER_PATH export CC CXX RANLIB STRIP CC=${COMPILER_PATH}/gcc CXX=${COMPILER_PATH}/g++ RANLIB=${COMPILER_PATH}/ranlib STRIP=${COMPILER_PATH}/strip export C_INCLUDE_PATH LIBRARY_PATH CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH COMPILER_PATH export CC CXX RANLIB STRIP
    CXX=${COMPILER_PATH}/g++
    RANLIB=${COMPILER_PATH}/ranlib
    STRIP=${COMPILER_PATH}/strip
    export C_INCLUDE_PATH LIBRARY_PATH CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH COMPILER_PATH
    export CC CXX RANLIB STRIP
```

Note, the example is not for a kernel compile, just some webserver I was compiling for ARM, and I did not even set all the possible variables.